# ignore case for JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Давая ответ на заданный кодом вопрос пользователь не должен беспокоиться о регистре.

```
var what = prompt("Просто вопрос","");
 if( what == "Ответ"){
  alert("Да, ответ");
}else{
  alert("Нет не ответ");
}
```

Для достижения цели добавляю ignoreCase, получаю...

```
var what = prompt("Просто вопрос","");
 if( what.ignoreCase == "Ответ"){
  alert("Да, ответ");
 }else{
  alert("Нет не ответ");
 }
```

Скрипт запускается но совершенно IGNORE мои усилия. Или в JavaScript не так как в Java ?

Comment: можна попробовать привести оба .toLowerCase(), тоесть if(what.toLowerCase() == "Ответ".toLowerCase())

Comment: `ignoreCase` - свойство `RegExpObject`, а не строки https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_ignorecase.asp

Comment: Можно, и в нижний регистр, можно и в верхний. Но как не зависить от регистра? Спасибо.

Comment: @Igor Видимо я ещё очень далёк от разработки, статья не принесла мне ясности, добавил новую переменную которая равна первой сделал её  .ignoreCase , код запускается  но результата ноль.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, используйте регулярные выражения (заодно узнаете чего-нибудь новенького):

```js
var what = prompt("Просто вопрос","");
if (/^Ответ$/i.test(what)) {
  alert("Да, ответ.");
} else {
  alert("Нет, не ответ.");
}
```

`i` в конце говорит о том, что сравнение будет делаться без учета регистра

`^` - строка должна начинаться с текста, который идет за этим символом

`$` - строка должна заканчиваться текстом, который идет перед этим символом

Comment: Спасибо, эти символы - /^ и $/i  заменяют ignoreCase ? Всегда, в любом случае?

Comment: нет, косые означают, что это объект `Regular Expression`. Начните с чтения:  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: Спасибо, буду учит.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, в подобных случаях, принято приводить строку к нижнему(или верхнему регистру).

```js
var what = prompt("Просто вопрос","") + '';
if (what.toLowerCase() === 'ответ') {
  alert("Да, ответ");
} else {
  alert("Нет не ответ");
}
```

Comment: Я понял, пусть пишет как хочет, потом весь текст принудительно привожу к нижнему регистру и всё. :)